# c++ Templates causing errors with function below

Tags: c++, templates

ive just started learning c++ ,and ive been trying to figure out why im getting this problem , the code works fine when using standard data structures (was working with int) before however once i try to use templates instead been getting problems

hope ive posted this in the right section and will post more code if needed

```
83    template <class  t>
84    struct node
85    {
86        t number  ;
87        node *next ;
88   };
89   
90   bool isEmpty(node *head)
91   {
92      if (head == NULL)
93      {
94         return true;
95       }
96       else
97       {
98           return false;
99       }
100   }
```

Errors im getting .

```
91|error: missing template arguments before '*' token|
91|error: 'head' was not declared in this scope| 
92|error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token|
 ||=== Build finished: 3 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

thanks on any feedback i get :)

Comment: thanks , done what g-makulik mention and solved the issue i was having

Answer (score 3):

You'll need s.th. like:

```
template<class t>
bool isEmpty(node<t> *head) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`note` is a template, you need to instantiate it with a type, like

```
bool isEmpty(node<int> *head)
{
  return head == NULL; // compare to if/else, this is much neater, right?
}
```

or make `isEmpty` a template function

```
template<typename T>
bool isEmpty(node<T> *head)
{
  return head == NULL;
}
```